# How do I receive SMS request errors through my status callback?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I have a MessageStatusCallback on my Twilio application set up that's correctly receiving updates, but if I try to send an SMS message to a phone number that's been unsubscribed, I'll get an exception rather than a failed delivery through the callback. Is this by design? Is there a way to receive errors through my callback, or is there a different property I need to set?

I could write a try-catch but I feel like it's not ideal if I already have an endpoint to handle status updates.

Code snippets:

```
_app = ApplicationResource.Create(friendlyName: "MessageServiceApp",
           smsUrl: new 
           Uri("XXXXX"),
           smsMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
           messageStatusCallback: new Uri("XXXXX"));

var message = MessageResource.Create(
                to: to,
                from: from,
                body: body,
                applicationSid: _app.Sid);
```

Comment: can you post a snippet of your code so we can see where to help?

Comment: I added the code, basically I'm setting the message status callback in the app, then setting the application sid in the message, but if a number has been unsubscribed, it'll throw an exception rather than hitting the callback.

Comment: When you say `a phone number that's been unsubscribed` what do you mean by that? Unsubscribed from where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is by design that unsubscribed numbers (or non-existent numbers, or numbers you can't send SMS messages to) will respond immediately with an exception. This  in turn allows you to immediately respond to the issue within your system rather than having to wait for a callback.

I highly recommend that you try-catch around your API call anyway. Networks are fickle things so you should be prepared for network failure, API failure (though the [API uptime numbers](https://status.twilio.com/#month) are pretty good ;-) ) and other issues that will cause exceptions, like a number that cannot receive messages.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: That does help, appreciate the response. I did put a try-catch around it, thanks for the tip about considering fickle networks. Makes a lot of sense